# SQL Server - multiuser authorization on single Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, database-administration

Our SQL server has 2 SQL users as follows:

1. User A, which contain the following rules

   - DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE
   - having the authorization of only two databases A1 and A2 out of 10 databases
2. User B, which contain the same rules as user A

   - DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE
   - having the authorization of only two databases B1 and B2 out of 10 databases

As per the rule assigned when I logged in using user A, showing only A1 and A2 databases,
and using user B showing only B1 and B2 databases.

I want to create a new user (User C) who has the authorization to combine users A and B,
without changing the current authorization or privilege of existing users A and B.

i.e.User A having authorization of databases A1 and A2.
User B having authorization of databases B1 and B2.
**New user C having authorization of both databases A1, A2, B1, and B2.**

Can someone please suggest this is possible or not or another way to achieve this new user authorization scenario?

Comment: `User A` and `User B` are Sql Server logins, aren't they? You can create server roles with an appropriate set of prmissions and add  a login to the role[s].

Comment: Even if it's windows authentication, you can make a group for A1A2B1B2 and move the user between AD groups.

Answer (score 0):

> New user C having authorization of both databases A1, A2, B1, and B2.

[Create a Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-ver15) for C, and create a [Database User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-ver15) in A1, A2, B1, and B2 for C.  But there's no way to declare that Login C has all the database access of both A and B.